# Pygame window doesn't update when running from a function?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this pygame code that goes a little like this (obviously not my actual code since its a little long):

```
def draw():
    win.fill(color)
    <code for drawing stuff>
    pygame.display.update()

def stuff():
    while doingStuff:
       <some lines of code>
       draw()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
while True:
    <some lines of code>
    if conditionMet:
       stuff()
    draw()
```

The problem is that when the "stuff" function runs, the pygame window freezes and doesnt update until it leaves the function. The draw function is correct I think, as it runs fine as long as it isn't in the function.

How do I make the pygame window keep updating whilst the function runs?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use threading or multiprocessing, because it is essential that you understand why your main render function is 'freezing'.

This means while your main method always renders everything so fast in a loop, that you don't see how long the draw() methods needs to calculate the new scene, it becomes obvious how long the stuff() or condition method needs to evaluate a result. Your main loop for drawing freezes because the calculation of the inner while loop from stuff() takes so long to complete. This is my assumption.

This happens because you program sequential. To solve this you need to put the stuff() function into its own program space - or better process space which is usually done with threads, which are subprocesses of your main process.

On the other hand you could try to speed up your stuff() method.